# Updating Query results from the result of a previous query in CSHTML

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, linq

I have a View page from a .NET Core project that depicts two ViewBags (ViewBag.Projects and ViewBag.VProjectTasks) result sets that were generated from its Index Controller.  These two Select DropDowns are from a top-level Form that contains other input and textarea fields.  They are all part of a View page that collects information for a specific project.

In My Database, I have two Tables.  One contains the list of Project names with an ID, such as:  ID, Project.  The Second Table contains the list of Tasks with their Project IDs, such as: ID, ProjectID, Task.

Currently, I am creating two ViewBags from the Index Controller that I am displaying all Projects and All Tasks on the Page, which is getting messy because I am getting to a point where I do not remember which task belongs to which Project.  I would like to fix that problem by using the result from one Query to display data for the following Query, in real-time or dynamically.

The first ViewBag contains the Project Field from the Project Table.  Once a Client or User selects a Specific Project from the Project Select DropDown, then, I would like to use the ID from that Result to Generate the Data Set for the ViewBag.VProjectTasks, thereby displaying only the Tasks for that specific Project, dynamically.

```
<form method="POST" asp-controller=TimeTracker asp-action="Create" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <input class="form-control" asp-for=Date type="text">
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="GrandTotal" type="hidden">
    </div>
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group service-line-field ">
            <label for="Project" class="control-label">Project List</label>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for=Project>
                @foreach(var prj in ViewBag.Projects)
                {                                
                    <option value="@prj.Project">@prj.Project</option>
                }
                </select>
            <span class="form-group-highlight"></span>
            <span class="form-group-bar"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group activity-field ">
            <label for="Task" class="control-label">Task</label>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="Task">
            @foreach(var prj in ViewBag.VProjectTasks)
            {                                
                <option value="@prj.Task">@prj.Task</option>
            }
            </select>
            <span class="form-group-highlight"></span>
            <span class="form-group-bar"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
<br>
<div class="row text-right">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="btn-group dropup dropdown-toggle-wrapper">
            <button class="btn btn-m btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Is this possible?  I am trying to keep the Database credentials from being exposed in the View, while maintaining a steady flow of dynamic data for that Vew page.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend you to use ajax for retrieve all tasks
then add id for both select and remove second select options like this

```html
<select id="project" class="form-control" asp-for=Project>
                @foreach(var prj in ViewBag.Projects)
                {                                
                    <option value="@prj.Project">@prj.Project</option>
                }
                </select>
 <select id="task" class="form-control" asp-for="Task">
           
            </select>
```

then add onchange for product to retrieve task by project id value using ajax
like this

```js
$("#Project").on("change", function() {
           
                function ("/api/ProjectTasks/"+parseInt($("#Project").val()), {}, "json", success) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: paramters,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: returnFormat,
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);
                let htmlData = "<option value='' selected disabled hidden>select task...</option>";
                            
                            for (let i = 0; i < Object.values(data)[1].length; i++) {
                                htmlData = htmlData + Template(Object.values(data)[1][i]);
                                }
                            $("#task").html(htmlData);
            },
            type: 'GET',
        });
    }
             function Template(item) {
                        let itemHtml = "<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.taskname + "</option>";
                        return itemHtml;
                    }
```